# Do modern hard drives have a built-in timer to stop the drive after a set time?

Tags: windows

Yes, of course one can use the Power Management options in Windows to set a time-out to spin down a hard drive. But I'm wondering if there is a timer within the drive's firmware that also does that? It just seems that after a while, the drive spins up after not being accessed for some minutes, regardless of the operating system's spin-down settings. This is assuming that the operating system's hard drive is set to never shut down. Perhaps it's my imagination....

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: Turning the disk on and off is **the most important responsibility the firmware has**

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Hard drives have had this capability in firmware for decades, however it remains an optional feature so not all drives have it.

Furthermore, there are multiple implementations. Some drives obey the standard ATA timeout commands, some drives can be configured via the ATA APM commands, some drives can only be configured by manufacturer-proprietary tools, and some drives have it as a mandatory feature that cannot be configured at all.

It is *typically* "Green" drives and laptop drives that have the feature enabled by default, but there is no universal rule - all manufacturers and vendors do things differently.